¿Como ejecuto un formulario en java?
Estoy tratando de jecutar un formulario para insertar registros en una base datos, pero al tratar de ejecuralo, me da este error "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: GroupLayout can only be used with one Container at a time" no se que pase, porque otros formularios que tengo los ejecuta con normalidad.
También tengo clases que hacen la inserción de datos pero no sé si tengan algo que ver, porque como dije, otros formularios si los ejecuta con normalidad
Este es el código del formulario:
public class Frm_Ingreso extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    
    
        public ArrayList<Pk_Clases.Ingreso> listacitis = new ArrayList();
        private final Cls_Ingreso CC;
        int num=0;

    public Frm_Ingreso() {
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        CC = new Pk_Clases.Cls_Ingreso();
        listacitis = CC.generarLista();          
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    
        private void Btn_ingresarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       int res = 0,op=-1;
        int id = 0;
       int id_ingreso=0, id_paciente=0;
      String diagnostico=null;
       Timestamp fecha_ingreso=null; 
       Timestamp fecha_salida=null;
               
        if(CT_Id_ingreso.getText().equals(""))
            op=0;
        else{
            id_ingreso = Integer.parseInt(CT_Id_ingreso.getText());
        }
        
        if(CT_id_paciente.getText().equals(""))
            op=0;
        else{
           id_paciente = Integer.parseInt(CT_id_paciente.getText());
        }
        
        
       if (JD_Fecha_Ingreso.getDate() != null && JD_Fecha_Salida.getDate() != null) {
        fecha_ingreso = new Timestamp(JD_Fecha_Ingreso.getDate().getTime());
        fecha_salida = new Timestamp(JD_Fecha_Salida.getDate().getTime());
       }  
       else {
        op = 0;
       }
       
       
       if(CT_Diagnostico.getText().equals(""))
            op=0;
        else{
            diagnostico = CT_Diagnostico.getText();
        }
        
        
        if(op==-1)
         res = CC.insertarDatos(id_ingreso, id_paciente, fecha_ingreso, fecha_salida, diagnostico);
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Falta datos de llenar");
 
    }     
        
     public static void main(String args[]) {
       
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Frm_Ingreso().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Pero en ese código no aparece ningún GroupLayout. Aquí tienen la misma excepción que tú pero incluyen el stack trace donde aparece qué linea de código concreta está dando el error. Fíjate en qué linea de tu código se está produciendo el error e intenta incluirla aquí como un ejemplo mínimo reproducible.
